# Setting user input from html to value in google sheets with GAS

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have HTML code with some JS as follows:

```
    <form>
    Object: <input type="text" name="object">
<br>
brand: <input type="text" name="brand">
<br> 
<br>
 color: <input type="text" name="color">
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"onclick="doTest()">
</form>
  <h3>Results</h3>
  formValues.object = <span id="object"></span><br>
  formValues.brand = <span id="brand"></span><br>
  formValues.color = <span id="color"></span><br>

<script id="jsbin-javascript">
    var formValues = {};
function inputObj(formNR, defaultValues) { 
  var inputs = formNR.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    formValues[inputs[i].name] = defaultValues[i];
    if(inputs[i].type === 'text') {
      inputs[i].value = defaultValues[i];                            
      document.getElementById(inputs[i].name).innerHTML = defaultValues[i];
    }
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      formValues[this.name] = this.value;
      document.getElementById(this.name).innerHTML = this.value;
    }, false);
  }
}
var defValues =['','',''];
inputObj(document.forms[0], defValues); 


</script>
```

When the user inputs some text, this text becomes a variable. E.g there is a variable called "formValues.object". Then I want to take the value of this variable and write it onto a google sheet using the following code

```
      function doTest() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I2').setValue("   ");
      }
```

The problem is that since the data I want to enter is a variable I do not know what I have to put between the .setValue brackets in order for the data the variable stores to appear in cell I2 of the google sheet when the submit button is pressed (I have already figured out how to link the submit button with the function).

Comment: This solution might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329834/using-email-address-from-external-html-file-to-send-email-via-google-apps-script/47331839#47331839

Answer (score 0):

If your value is an object and you want to put it into a single cell you will need to convert the variable to a string.

```
  function doTest() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I2').setValue(JSON.stringify(MyVariable));
  }
```